# copy command is not working on all dynamically generated table items - jsp spring boot

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, onclick

I'm creating a table with 4 columns(id, DestinationURL, ShortLink, Action(copy)). All the data is coming from the database and I'm creating the content with a for-each loop in my JSP page. The output page looks like this
[image: url details img]
Before action column there is a hidden field that hold the baseURL+ ShortURL i.e. `http://localhost:8080/qcX4h6`. Here is my code to create this table

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered vertical-alien-middle">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
           <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Destination Url</th>
               <th>Short URL</th>
               <!--<th width="20%" colspan="3">Actions</th>-->
               <th>Actions</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           <c:forEach var="links" items="${data}">
               <tr>
                   <td>${links.getId()}</td>
                   <td>${links.getDestinationUrlLink()}</td>
                   <td>${links.getShortUrlLink()}</td>
                   <td id="copyTd" hidden="">
                       <input type="text" id="${links.getId()}" value="${baseUrl}/${links.getShortUrlLink()}">
                   </td>
                   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="copyShortLink(${links.getId()})">
                            Copy
                       </button>
                   </td>
                   <!--<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Edit</button></td>-->
                   <!--<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button></td>-->
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The copy command is working fine for the first button but not for all subsequent buttons. Here is my javascript function

```
function copyShortLink(id) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    var td = document.getElementById("copyTd");
    /* Select the text field */
    td.hidden = false;
    input.select();
    input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");
    td.hidden = true;
}
```

So my question is how can I make the other buttons work with the same function. I'm passing the hidden input field's id in the function so why it works only for the first button and not for others.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code i.e: `id="copyTd"` this will be copied the first row ,as same id cannot used for all row ,instead you can append some value to your `<td id="">` i.e : `copyTd_${links.getId()}` here , add link id to uniquely identify each `td`. and just add `document.getElementById("copyTd_" + id);` this your `js` code.Changes you need to do in your code is as follows :

***Jsp code*** :

```
<tr>
  <td>${links.getId()}</td>
  <td>${links.getDestinationUrlLink()}</td>
  <td>${links.getShortUrlLink()}</td>
  <!--added links_id to your td-->
  <td id="copyTd_${links.getId()}" hidden="">
   ...
  </td>

</tr>
```

---

***Javscript code*** :

```
function copyShortLink(id) {
  var input = document.getElementById(id);
  /*add same id to select particular td*/
  var td = document.getElementById("copyTd_" + id);
...

}
```

---

***With Dummy Data*** :

```js
function copyShortLink(id) {
  var input = document.getElementById(id);
  var td = document.getElementById("copyTd_" + id);
  /* Select the text field */
  td.hidden = false;
  input.select();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
 /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("Text copied ..." + input.value);
  td.hidden = true;

}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered vertical-alien-middle">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Destination Url</th>
      <th>Short URL</th>
      <!--<th width="20%" colspan="3">Actions</th>-->
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="links" items="${data}">
      <tr>
        <td>${links.getId()}</td>
        <td>${links.getDestinationUrlLink()}</td>
        <td>abc.in</td>
        <td id="copyTd_abc" hidden="">
          <input type="text" id="abc" value="abc.in">
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="copyShortLink('abc')">
                            Copy
                       </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>${links.getId()}</td>
        <td>${links.getDestinationUrlLink()}</td>
        <td>abcd.com</td>
        <td id="copyTd_abcd" hidden="">
          <input type="text" id="abcd" value="abcd.com">
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="copyShortLink('abcd')">
                            Copy
                       </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```